Type hint for a function returning the same type not working
What is wrong in this example? Isn't the str -> str case included in T -> T ?
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")
def unch(arg:T) -> T:
    if isinstance(arg, str):
        return arg 
    return arg

mypy checking result:
# error: Incompatible return value type (got "str", expected "T")


Update 1: deleted

Update 2: don't know why, but this works:
from typing import TypeVar, Any

T = TypeVar("T", str, Any)
def unch(arg:T) -> T:
    if isinstance(arg, str):
        return arg
    return arg


PyRight accepts this. I suspect it's a bug in mypy. The type narrowing should, in some sense, imply that T ~ str.

Possible duplicate: What is the proper type-hinting for this function which accepts either an instance or a builder, and returns the instance?. See also this open Mypy issue linked from the accepted answer.

(Note that PyRight does correctly reject an attempt to return arg + "foo" from the body of the if statement, as it recognizes that even if you know the runtime type is str, the only thing you can do with a "T-str" is return it unchanged; the function is not allowed to make use of runtime information about T.)

@InSync I'm sorry, If the other thread is a duplicate or not. It discusses typing on a more advanced level than I am familiar with. I found another mypy issue that is almost the same.
